# Forward mouse scroll event from child UserControl to parent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, user-controls

I want to forward the mouse scroll event from a control to its direct parent (which is also `UserControl` in my case).

How is this possible?

**Edit** The control is added to a control that is scrollable. Like a memo-edit for example.

When the user scrolls in the memo-control, the memo-control is scrolled (!)
But when the user scrolls on top of the custom control the event is not forwared to the parent control and the memo-control does not scroll.

Comment: what is the point of question? you cant get parent control or dont know how to rise scroll event in parent control?

Comment: Plese, specify do you use WinForms or WPF (in WPF there is routed events for example)

Comment: It already works this way, Windows automatically bubbles the message from parent to parent until somebody handles the message.  Find out why your "custom control" is grabbing the event.

Comment: @HansPassant as you point out in another answer of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362428/setting-focus-to-a-net-usercontrol) this isn't true

Comment: That has nothing to do with it, this question is about the mouse scroll message.