# Enter event not firing in Panel inside a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I added a Panel inside a UserControl i design time.

Then, I added this control to a form.

I want to show a focus dashed border when the control has the focus.

Unfortunately, the `Enter` event from the panel never fires. I only get a fire when I click on the user control itself.

To extend this question. How can I forward events from controls inside a user control to the base user control? A comment from Hans Passant in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041923/forward-mouse-scroll-event-from-child-usercontrol-to-parent) question says that **by default** events are forwarded to their direct parent. I didn't change any of the control's properties. What am I doing wrong? Is there an obvious property I need to change on each control i order to force it to forward unhandled events?

I am using `DevExpress` controls but this behavior is same in windows `WinForms` controls.

**edit:** I understand that panel might not be able to get focus. If this is true, how do I forward each mouse event to the parent control?

Comment: Shouldn't you just use the `Enter` and `Leave` events of the UserControl to just invalidate the panel inside it?

Comment: If I click the panel, the UserControl's Enter event does not fire. That's my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panel not getting focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, from inside your UserControl, handle the panel's MouseDown event and set the focus to the parent control:

```
public UserControl1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
}

void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (!this.Focused)
    this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Now what about when the control gains focus by some other means, like through using the Tab key?

Comment: @dynamichael A UserControl has a standard Enter event for that.  Unless that UserControl has a focusable control like a TextBox in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use panel1.Select() on MouseClick event of the panel and you will be able to trigger panel1.Enter and panel1.Leave